# How to render Html to image format?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Render HTML as an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334532/render-html-as-an-image)

I have the the html "My test Text"
Now I want to render this html to image format.
I have the code which render teh simple text to image . I want to render html with style implemented on it in a image format.
How can I do it in C#?
is there any way without using the third part software.

Thanks
Dalvir