# How to render html to image format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to render "Hello dalvir" to  image format so that hello dalvir shows in red color in image. How i can do it in C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render Html to image format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302293/how-to-render-html-to-image-format)

Answer (score 1):

here is code...

```
Font MyFont = new Font(FontFamily, Font,FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
MyGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpImage);
MyGraphics.Clear(Color.FromName("Red"));
MyGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
MyGraphics.DrawString("Hello dalvir", MyFont,
                    new SolidBrush(Color.FromName("Red")), 0, 0);
MyGraphics.Flush();
```

Comment: I want use html directly like "hello davir " wil be in html tags that having the style to apply teh red color.
I this case what i have to do?