# Render HTML Code String to Image C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to Render HTML Code to an Image with C#.

Can I do this without taking a snapshot from a URL

if i have:

```
string s = "<html>..</html>";
```

can i convert it to image or Bitmap Object

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render HTML as an Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334532/render-html-as-an-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the HTML to a WebControl, then create a screen shot... simple.

Answer (score -4):

You can convert your code into a byte-array and then will be able to convert the byte-array to a bitmap object.

Comment: Are we trolling in answers now?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.